# Ansible variable from github actions secret

Tags: ansible, github-actions

I'm trying to use Githubactions secrets in my ansible playbooks that will then be passed to templates, but there is no lookup plugin for GHA. This does not work:

```
- hosts: the-host
  vars:
    influxdb_pass: "{{ lookup('env', 'secret.INFLUXDB_PASS' }}"
```

My workaround is to expose the secrets through GHA environment variables and just use the ansible env lookup plugin:

```
name: Pull Request - Ansible
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Config updates
        env:
          INFLUXDB_PASS: ${{ secrets.INFLUXDB_PASS }}
```

```
- hosts: the-host
  vars:
    influxdb_pass: "{{ lookup('env', 'INFLUXDB_PASS' }}"
```

The problem is I manage plenty of secrets and it is annoying having to:

1. Add the secret in the repo settings
2. Define the variable in ansible-playbook
3. Explicitly expose the secrets through environment variables in the GHA workflow.

When in other CI tools such as Gitlab you don't need to do the explicit secret expose, you can consume secrets directly as env vars.

Does anyone have advice on a better approach for GHA?

Comment: *Add the secret in the repo settings* well, you don't _have_ to do that -- such a situation is the problem ansible-vault is designed to solve: put the secrets in the repo, but only unlock them in CI

Answer (score 0):

you can pass them as extra-vars,

ansible-playbook /path_to/ansible-playbook/sample.yml -i /path_to/ansible-playbook/inventory.txt --extra-vars "host=$secrets.INFLUXDB_PASS"

I might not be correct in syntax but I think you have got the gist. please try it.

Comment: i think this is the least anoying way, sadly if you have a centralized playbook, still need in each gha call add the variable